# how to synchronize N processes

Tags: c++

Q1. (see code below) If I comment the while loop. I can communicate through IPC. but why with while loop, I'm getting no output?

Q2. Is there a better way to communicate between processes rather than using pipe, (through signals or semaphores if yes then kindly provids some examples.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int person_from_whom_token_starts =1;
    bool started = false ;
    int tok_value = 3;
    int iveToken = 4;
    int tok_value_const = 5;

    int x;
    bool y;

    int fd[2];
    int status = 0;
    pipe(fd);

    switch(fork()){
        case -1:
            cout << "ERRR" << endl;
            break;
        case 0:
            close(fd[0]);
            dup2(fd[1],1);
            while(1){
                cout << person_from_whom_token_starts << started << tok_value << iveToken << tok_value_const;
                sleep(3); 
            }
            exit(0);
            break;
        default:
            sleep(1);
            dup2(fd[0],0);
            close(fd[1]);

            cin >> x >> y;
            cout << "x: " << x << "\ny: " << y << endl;
            //wait(&status);
            break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You haven't thought about [flushing](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/flush) the output?

Comment: @MuhammadRehanQadri: The comment includes a _link_ to documentation of the correct function. What else do you want?

Comment: Thanks a lot Joachim Pileborg, my problem solved by inserting << endl in cout in while.

Comment: Q1. Answered! 

Someone please answer question 2 as well.

Comment: Using pipes is the simples and most straightforward way for IPC. There are other ways (like semaphores or signals like you mention) but if you want to send data back-and-forth between the processes you can't use all process-synchronization primitives, pipes is the simplest to send data. You may want to read about [shared memory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shared_memory) too of course.

Comment: Some examples of signals and semaphores for 'process' synchronization would be greatly helpful.

Comment: Since you're on a POSIX platform (as indicated by the `<unistd.h>` header file), do a search for "POSIX semaphores" and "POSIX signals" (and read about [signals](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/signal.h.html) and the [`signal(7)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html) manual page).